# Ajax not updating the div in Django

Tags: python, jquery, django, ajax, django-views

I'm using Ajax for like button in my Blog. When I hit `Like` button, the count is updated in DB but it is not reflecting in my page(The button should change to `'Unlike'` without reloading the page). But, when i refresh the page, it is reflecting as expected.

views.py:

```
def like_post(request):
    user = request.user
    post_id = request.POST.get('id')
    post_obj = get_object_or_404(Post, id=post_id)

    if user in post_obj.liked.all():
        post_obj.liked.remove(user)
    else:
        post_obj.liked.add(user)

    like, created = Like.objects.get_or_create(user=user, post_id=post_id)

    if not created:
        if like.value == 'Like':
            like.value = 'Unlike'
        else:
            like.value = 'Like'

    like.save()
    context={
    'post': post_obj
    }

    if request.is_ajax():
        html = render_to_string('blog/like_section.html', context, request=request)
        return JsonResponse({'form': html})
```

Ajax:

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(event){
            $(document).on('click', '#like', function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
                var pk = $(this).attr('value');
                $.ajax({
                    type : 'POST',
                    url : {% url 'like-post' %},
                    data : {'id' : pk, 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'}, 
                    dataType : 'json',
                    success : function(response){
                        $('#like-section').html(response['form'])
                        console.log($('#like-section').html(response['form']));
                    },
                    error : function(rs, e){
                        console.log(rs.responseText);
                    },
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Html:

```
<form action="{% url 'like-post' %}" method="POST">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {% if user not in post.liked.all %}
        <button id="like" name="post_id" value="{{ post.id }}" class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" type="submit">Like</button>
      {% else %}
        <button id="like" name="post_id" value="{{ post.id }}" class="btn btn-info mb-4" type="submit">Unlike</button>
      {% endif %}

</form>
```

urls.py:

```
path('likes/', views.like_post, name='like-post'),
```

There is no error in the console as well

```
jQuery.fn.init {}
XHR finished loading: POST "http://localhost:8000/likes/".
```

Comment: what does `response['form']` returning ? Does it shows correct button ?

Comment: Why do you return the whole form as json response instead of like or dislike string and in the success function you set that value for the button html

Comment: I'm a beginner, i followed along the Youtube & got this. Please let me know if there is any alternatives.

Comment: It looks, some issue in success. I tried commenting out success in ajax, the result is same as now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the result just by reloading the div in response function.

```
success : function(response){
                 $(".like-section").load(" .like-section")
                 },
```